# Skip and Replace string using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Using the below code I see the result as

```
cardetails =  "<ul>" + car.model.Product.Replace("•", "<li>").Replace("\n", "</li>") + "</li></ul>";
```

Strng 1:
"Product":"• Hatchback\n• Hyundai"

- Hatchback
- Hyundai

In the same string I have added Sedan as new type now the complete string is
**"Product":"• Hatchback\n• Sedan\n• Hyundai"** here I need to skip Hatchback and retrieve only Sedan in First list item using conditional operator

- Sedan
- Hyundai

```
 cardetails = carType == CarTypes.Hatchback.ToString()
            ? "<ul>" + car.model.Product.Replace("•", "<li>").Replace("\n", "</li>") + "</li></ul>"
            : "How to add logic here to retrieve Sedan in first <li> and skip hatchback";
```

How can I achieve this

Comment: I don't see any LINQ here. Is this code your delegate within a LINQ call e.g. `cars.Select(c => c.CarType == CarType.Hatchback ? "" : ... )` ? Don't name enums in the plural unless they're `[Flags]`, by the way

Comment: Non-understandable question :|

Comment: Trying to manipulate strings like this is only going to make things harder for you in the long run. My suggestion: 1. Get your `car.Model.Product` value into a format that's easier to work with (e.g. Manufacturer > Shapes). 2. Generate whatever HTML you need to from that.

Comment: Can I ask why you are building a string like that that contains HTML tags? Usually doing that is a "very bad idea", hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing the behaviour of `Skip()`. I assume that `car.model.Product` is a string, which means `Skip` will treat the string as an `IEnumerable<char>` and therefore `Skip(1)` will **skip one character** in the string:

```
var myString = "this is a string";
var result = myString.Skip(1);
// result == "his is a string"
```

One way you could solve this is by splitting the string into the parts you are interested in and then skip the first part you want to discard:

```cs
var productParts = car.model.Product
    // We don't really care about the line breaks
    .Replace(@"\n", "")
    // Split the string and remove any empty parts and
    // remove (trim) spaces from the ends of each part
    .Split("•", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntriesTrimEntries)
    // Wrap each part in a <li> tag
    .Select(part => $"<li>{part}</li>");

cardetails = carType == CarTypes.Hatchback.ToString()
    ? $"<ul>{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, productParts)}</ul>"
    : $"<ul>{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, productParts.Skip(1))}</ul>";
// Notice: we skip the first (Hatchback) part above
```

Comment: I have a list with three values  <ul>
<li> Hatchback</li><li> Hatchback</li>
<li> Hyundai </li>
</ul>

Comment: @SayeedAhmed Do you mean something is wrong?

Comment: @  Xerillio At present I can successfully display Sedan values but not for Hatchback type
Below is final string I get  <li> Hatchback</li><li> Sedan</li>
<li> Hyundai </li>, Whenever i get Car model as Hatchback I need to remove <li>Sedan</li> from the list which is not happening using skip(2) and I tried with RemoveAt property which throws compile error as Void cannot convert to String, Appreciate your help,!

Comment: @  Xerillio Code I used  -   car.ModelType == CarModels.Sedan.ToString() ? $"{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, productParts.Skip(1))}" : $"{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, productParts.RemoveAt(2))};// RemoveAt throws compilation error , If I use Skip(2) to remove Middle element from string It's removing top 2

Comment: @SayeedAhmed Yea, you can't do that with standard LINQ. The easiest would be to turn it into a list first (`ToList()`) and then remove it like you've tried. But if you have multiple conditions/checks like this you should consider something smarter than relying on the values being at specific indexes in the list.

Comment: I have achieved it with two lines of code, is there any way I can improve the code with one single statement   var sedanTxt= car.model.Product.Replace("•", "<li>").Split('\n').Select(part => $"{part}").Where((x, y) => y % 2 == 0).ToList();
            var hatchBackTxt= car.model.Product.Replace("•", "<li>").Split('\n').Select(part => $"{part}").ToList();            
                descriptionText = car.Model == Models.hatchback ? $"{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, hatchBackTxt.Skip(1))}" : $"{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sedanTxt)}";

Comment: @SayeedAhmed this code is very fragile. The smallest changes in the input will break you code. You need to think about parsing the input in a way so it's not dependable on the number of elements and line breaks etc. One-liner code snippets are not a sign of good coding. You should focus on making it readable.

Comment: Can you pls check my post so far I haven't got any answers yet posted on (13/6/2021) if you have any answers for this.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67961086/api-abuse-security-vulnerability-issue-mvc-app